# Why does implicit conversion require "inbetween" assembly?

Tags: c#, assemblies, implicit-conversion, build-dependencies

I have two projects, *Project A* is a WPF Application and *Project B* is a WPF Control Library.

*Project A* References default WPF stuff. But not `System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon`.

*Project B* defines a class `MainWindow` which inherits from `RibbonWindow`, located in the `System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon` Assembly.

Inside the App.xaml.cs im going to set the `Current.MainWindow` instance to a `MainWindow` of *Project B*

```
Current.MainWindow = factory.CreateMainWindow(); // Returns of type `MainWindow`
```

This causes the following Build-Errors:

**CS0012**: The type 'RibbonWindow' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

**CS0029**: Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyNamespace.MainWindow' to 'System.Windows.Window'

> It can be solved referencing `System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon` from *Project A*

As you can see, `MainWindow` is a `RibbonWindow` which is a `Window`.
`Current.MainWindow` requires a `Window` to be set. The `MainWindow` returned by `factory.CreateMainWindow()` is to be converted implicitly to `Window`.

#### Why does the implicit conversion require Assemblys of all in-between-Types to be referenced?

Comment: "`MainWindow` is a `RibbonWindow` which is a `Window`" - **you** know that. **I** know that. The *compiler* can't know that until it sees that assembly. The compiler only works (when compiling each project) with the source code files and the assemblies *you* tell it it should pay attention to via references.

Comment: @dam thanks, can you provide a bit more about the background of how the compiler does do this? Is it possible to tell the Compiler about those inbetween types without referencing the assembly?